# Database Login ao gerar relatório no Crystal Reports VS2008 - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, relatório, crystal-reports, dataset

Bom dia\tarde\noite

Eu já sei que existem alguns tópicos relacionados a essa mesma questão que estou levantando, porém nenhum participava exatamente das mesmas condições que levaram ao mesmo acontecimento, como assim?

Bom, vamos lá!

- Importei de outro projeto os Datasets bem como seus respectivos rpts
  e os formulários de relatório.vb.
- Adicionei como referência no projeto o .exe da outra aplicação.
- Fui no Set Datasource Location dos rpts e alterei o Class Name para o
  projeto atual.

A necessidade de importar esses itens existentes é que a aplicação em questão necessitará gerar os mesmos relatórios que a outra.

Implementei mais algumas coisas no projeto e tudo certo, mas na hora de gerar o relatório pede login e senha do Dataset no qual eu jogo as informações tratadas. Tenho vários Datasets para vários relatórios.

Desde já agradeço qualquer participação.

Segue o exemplo de um dos tipos de chamadas para gerar o relatório.

```
Sub ResultadoProgesterona(ByVal C As String, ByVal N As String, ByVal Imprimir As Boolean)

        Dim SqlStr As String = "SELECT UTILIZAD"
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection(myConnStr)
        Con.Open()
        Dim SqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim DtSet As New DataSet
        SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(SqlStr, Con)
        SqlAdapter.Fill(DtSet, "ExameItem")
        Dim row As DataRow
        row = DtSet.Tables(0).NewRow()

        DtSet.Tables(0).Rows.Add(row)
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetDataSource(DtSet)
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1))
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6))
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3))
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(4))
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", N)
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(5))
        RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.SetParameterValue("", DtSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2))
        If Imprimir Then
            RelatorioProgesterona.RelProgesterona1.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 1, 1)
        Else

            CarregaForm(RelatorioProgesterona, pprincipal)
            RelatorioProgesterona.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

        End If

        DtSet.Dispose()
        DtSet = Nothing
        SqlAdapter.Dispose()
        SqlAdapter = Nothing
        Con.Close()
        Con.Dispose()
        Con = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: EXEMPLO]

Comment: Andrew, não existe nenhum problema em você mesmo postar a resposta para o seu problema. Por favor, publique a resposta para o seu problema (como resposta). Assim todos saberão que a sua dúvida foi resolvida e poderão consultar os seus métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além de fazer todos os passos citados acima faltou mais um:

- Importei de outro projeto os **Datasets** bem como seus respectivos **.rpts**
  e os formulários de **relatório.vb**.
- Adicionei como referência no projeto o **.exe** da outra aplicação.
- Fui no Set **Datasource Location** dos rpts e alterei o **Class Name** para o
  projeto atual.
- Ir nas **propriedades** do **CrystalReportViewer** e Alterar o **ReportSource**
  para a **referência do projeto atual**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero poder ajudar alguém que passe pela mesma dificuldade. []'s